# How to check object overlapping in carousel - JavaScript

Tags: javascript, carousel, overlay, overlapping

I have a javascript carousel with blocks of different colors (1,2,3 ...). I need to check object overlay.Div block - INFO is fixed over carousel. For example, if block #1(grey one) will be under block - INFO(like in the photo), the text from block #1 should appeared in block INFO. Then, we start scrolling carousel. Block #4 became under INFO block and then text from #4 should appered in block INFO. If you have any ideas how to create it, please write.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/eFIv3.png

Comment: Look into how to use IntersectionObserver. If you put up a working set of code we could help you more.